# MySQL query using limit and offset does not return expected ordered results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the count of entries by users grouped by year, month and user name from a table which has 45M entries. The query result has around 4M records which I wasn't able to get in one go so I decided to use limit and offset.

To retrieve the first 1M records I've written the query below:

```sql
select SQL_BIG_RESULT uis.nick, uis.user_id, CONCAT(t.year, '-', LPAD(t.month, 2, 0)) AS DATE, t.count 
from (select SQL_BIG_RESULT e.user_id, YEAR(e.created_at) as year, MONTH(e.created_at) as month, COUNT(*) AS count
        from entries e
        group by YEAR(e.created_at), MONTH(e.created_at), e.user_id
        limit 1000000
     ) t
inner join users u on u.id = t.user_id
inner join user_infos ui on ui.user_id = u.id
inner join user_identifiers uis on uis.user_info_id = ui.id
order by t.year, t.month, uis.nick;
```

To retrieve the second 1M records I've set an offset of 999998 so I would have 2 overlapping rows so that I could double check that it's correct, hence this query below:

```sql
select SQL_BIG_RESULT uis.nick, uis.user_id, CONCAT(t.year, '-', LPAD(t.month, 2, 0)) AS DATE, t.count 
from (select SQL_BIG_RESULT e.user_id, YEAR(e.created_at) as year, MONTH(e.created_at) as month, COUNT(*) AS count
        from entries e
        group by YEAR(e.created_at), MONTH(e.created_at), e.user_id
        limit 999998, 1000000
     ) t
inner join users u on u.id = t.user_id
inner join user_infos ui on ui.user_id = u.id
inner join user_identifiers uis on uis.user_info_id = ui.id
order by t.year, t.month, uis.nick;
```

Then to compare the results and double check, I've got the tail of the first 1M records and the head of the second 1M records. There should be 2 overlapping records in my understanding -since I've used an offset of 999998- but there is something wrong.

It's also evident that there is something wrong with the query because the first file ends with `zzzzz` but then the second file starts with `0 3 kalem ucu` which should not be after `z` in alphabetical order.

```sh
$ tail entry_counts_by_users_1_1m.csv

| user_nick   | user_id | date    | entry_count | 
|-------------|---------|---------|-------------| 
| zskal       | 493395  | 2013-05 | 8           | 
| zuhanzee    | 397659  | 2013-05 | 2           | 
| zulmet      | 446672  | 2013-05 | 74          | 
| zuluuuuuu   | 1240043 | 2013-05 | 9           | 
| zverkov     | 502616  | 2013-05 | 2           | 
| zvezdite    | 750458  | 2013-05 | 1           | 
| zx          | 249598  | 2013-05 | 15          | 
| zyprexa 5mg | 779519  | 2013-05 | 16          | 
| zzgx        | 584985  | 2013-05 | 2           | 
| zzzzz       | 22730   | 2013-05 | 1           |
```

```sh
$ head entry_counts_by_users_1m_2m.csv

| nick          | user_id | DATE    | count | 
|---------------|---------|---------|-------| 
| 0 3 kalem ucu | 624699  | 2013-05 | 4     | 
| 0132          | 995914  | 2013-05 | 3     | 
| 03072010      | 960606  | 2013-05 | 9     | 
| 0312020008    | 804486  | 2013-05 | 2     | 
| 0326          | 446816  | 2013-05 | 1     | 
| 05            | 575534  | 2013-05 | 1     | 
| 05012009      | 1171153 | 2013-05 | 6     | 
| 0904          | 514964  | 2013-05 | 2     | 
| 0kmzeka       | 777191  | 2013-05 | 4     |
```

Could you help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

```sql
+-----------+
| @@version |
+-----------+
| 8.0.19    |
+-----------+
```

---

**UPDATE**

These are the results I get after using `ORDER BY` in my subquery:

```sql
select SQL_BIG_RESULT uis.nick, uis.user_id, CONCAT(t.year, '-', LPAD(t.month, 2, 0)) AS DATE, t.count
    from (select SQL_BIG_RESULT e.user_id, YEAR(e.created_at) as year, MONTH(e.created_at) as month, COUNT(*) AS count
            from entries e
            group by YEAR(e.created_at), MONTH(e.created_at), e.user_id
            order by year, month, user_id
            limit 1000000) t
    inner join users u on u.id = t.user_id
    inner join user_infos ui on ui.user_id = u.id
    inner join user_identifiers uis on uis.user_info_id = ui.id
```

For the first 1M records:

```sh
$ tail entry_counts_by_users_1_1m.csv

| user_name                  | user_id | date    | entry_count | 
|----------------------------|---------|---------|-------------| 
| statistic er               | 667546  | 2012-06 | 1           | 
| mula                       | 612905  | 2013-02 | 1           | 
| sisman cirkin bi de kezban | 1327434 | 2013-02 | 2           | 
| tyra34                     | 1329280 | 2013-03 | 1           | 
| ecemazkan                  | 1332628 | 2013-02 | 1           | 
| susamlicubuk               | 1333079 | 2013-02 | 1           | 
| hemenhemenherterim         | 631784  | 2011-04 | 1           | 
| umursamaz tavrin hastasi   | 1060158 | 2012-09 | 2           | 
| uslucocuk                  | 1254758 | 2012-09 | 1           | 
| dharamsala                 | 956110  | 2012-09 | 1           |
```

```sql
select SQL_BIG_RESULT uis.nick, uis.user_id, CONCAT(t.year, '-', LPAD(t.month, 2, 0)) AS DATE, t.count
    from (select SQL_BIG_RESULT e.user_id, YEAR(e.created_at) as year, MONTH(e.created_at) as month, COUNT(*) AS count
            from entries e
            group by YEAR(e.created_at), MONTH(e.created_at), e.user_id
            order by year, month, user_id
            limit 999998, 1000000) t
    inner join users u on u.id = t.user_id
    inner join user_infos ui on ui.user_id = u.id
    inner join user_identifiers uis on uis.user_info_id = ui.id
```

For the second 1M records:

```sh
$ head entry_counts_by_users_1m_2m.csv

| user_name | user_id | date    | entry_count | 
|-----------|---------|---------|-------------| 
| ssg       | 8097    | 2013-06 | 101         | 
| ssg       | 8097    | 2013-07 | 73          | 
| ssg       | 8097    | 2013-08 | 100         | 
| ssg       | 8097    | 2013-09 | 88          | 
| ssg       | 8097    | 2013-10 | 84          | 
| ssg       | 8097    | 2013-11 | 54          | 
| ssg       | 8097    | 2013-12 | 64          | 
| ssg       | 8097    | 2014-01 | 78          | 
| ssg       | 8097    | 2014-02 | 31          |
```

I still don't get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using the version 8.0.19

Comment: None of your queries order primarily by nick, so why do you expect your result files to be ordered by nick? Your limit query does not order by nick at all.

Comment: "To retrieve the first 1M records..." -- `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` doesn't make too much sense. You are not selecting the **first** 1M rows, but just **any** 1M rows.

Comment: @TheImpaler group by implicitly orders as well. Just nick is not involved in that ordering

Comment: @Shadow Is that a MySQL feature? That could work, but I didn't know about it.

Comment: If the order is wrong, shouldn't I get the two rows overlapping anyway from both queries since I set an offset of 999998? I was just ordering by nick in the end. @The Impaler, wouldn't it be the first 1M rows with the limit? And could you tell me the correct way of making the query please? Should I order by before the limit?

Comment: @Shadow *group by implicitly orders as well* not in MySql 8.0: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/paQr4yCZBHbYJHKwJvSofd/0

Comment: I understand that in the absence of `ORDER BY` then engine will return the rows in **any** order (though @Shadow disagrees with this statement). If the rows are returned in any order, then `LIMIT` won't work as you expect. I would suggest you add the `ORDER BY` and this problem may disappear; ...and it's very cheap to do.

Comment: Alright, I will add `ORDER BY` before limit, I think I've tried that before which didn't help me either as far as I remember, but I will do it again and share the results with you here.

Comment: Ordering will work to produce non-overlapping resultsets. However, ordering the subquery with the limit and the outer query differently will make it more difficult for you to check the results.

Comment: I've added an update to my question with the results from `ORDER BY` statement added to the subquery. I am still confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in MySQL 8.0.13, implicit ordering for `GROUP BY` [has been removed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html):

> Incompatible Change: The deprecated ASC or DESC qualifiers for GROUP BY clauses have been removed. Queries that previously relied on GROUP BY sorting may produce results that differ from previous MySQL versions. To produce a given sort order, provide an ORDER BY clause.

The implicit ordering has been deprecated since 5.6, so there has been some warning.

Your subquery is using `GROUP BY` with no `ORDER BY`.  The ordering of the result set is  not specified *and it might change from one run to the next*.  To produce a stable result, using an `ORDER BY` before the `LIMIT`.

Comment: Ouch, one more thing to watch out for.

Comment: I've updated my question with the `ORDER BY` statement added to my subquery. Can you check it, please?

Comment: But the `order by` is already before the `limit`, isn't it?

Comment: @AndréYuhai . . . Sorry, I was looking at the wrong query.

Comment: @AndréYuhai . . . Another issue is that if you are comparing `head` and `tail`, you need to guarantee that the result set is ordered.  So, you need an order by in the outer query.  Otherwise, the `join`s could mess up the ordering.

Comment: Oh, alright. I didn't know about that. I thought `inner join`s would just join in place in the ordered result set. I will try that as well and see, thank you.

Comment: @AndréYuhai . . . Both `order by`s are necessary -- the inner one to get the right set of rows and the outer one to ensure that they are in the right order.

Comment: If I just use the subquery then everything works like a charm, but the outer query messes things up even though I've used `order by date, uis.nick` for the outer query as well.

Comment: @AndréYuhai . . . Who knows where the `date` field is coming from if you use that.  The ordering should be `order by t.year, t.month, t.user_id` -- the same as in the subquery.

Comment: `date` was just the `concat` of `year` and `month` but now I'm trying as you've suggested.

Comment: After trying a few combinations of it I've finally got the correct results, haha. Thank you.